# Unable to install wine 2

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install wine using:

```
sudo apt-get install winehq-devel 2.8.0~xenial
```

and I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 2.8.0~xenial
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '2.8.0~xenial'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '2.8.0~xenial'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Spaces separate commands, options and arguments on the command line. Apt is looking for two packages. I'm not sure what should come before the version (. or _or -?) or if it should be there at all, but that's your problem

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you add the '2.8.0~xenial' to your command.  The [official installation page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) recommends to install with:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

Do you have special reasons to try to force a specific version (I guess this is what you want)?